# How to generate a stack trace upon division by zero with ghc 7.10.3?

Tags: haskell, stack-trace, partial-functions

If a program is run and crashes with the message "Divide by zero", what is the best way to identify where in the code this error was generated?

Comment: Can you qualify "best"? In general, stack traces don't make as much sense in a lazy functional language as you probably expect them to, so probably your "best" bet is to enable profiling. Otherwise, use [`CallStack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/GHC-Stack.html).

Comment: I guess I would settle for any method that identifies the line in source code at which the error occurs.  When you say enable profiling, does that mean I could run `stack build` with some extra parameters (which ones?), and then when I execute the program it will accompany the error with more information?

Answer (score 2):

GHC doesn't support stack traces as such because *there isn't a call stack*. The best you can do is to use the simulated stack trace machinery in the base module [`GHC.Stack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/GHC-Stack.html).

Starting with GHC 7.8, and thus available in 7.10.3, `GHC.Stack` exposes

```
errorWithStackTrace :: String -> a
```

which acts like `error` on normal builds but uses the SCC annotations (e.g., from `--fprof-auto`) to construct an approximate stack trace on profiled builds. You will need to recompile with profiling enabled to support this. If you are using cabal, you can run

```
cabal configure --enable-library-profiling --enable-executable-profiling
```

and rebuild.

Starting with GHC 8.0, `errorWithStackTrace` is deprecated and support for call-site generation is provided by the `HasCallStack` machinery.

Quoting now from the `GHC.Stack` documentation,

> A function can request its call-site with the `HasCallStack` constraint. For example, we can define
>
> ```
> errorWithCallStack :: HasCallStack => String -> a
> ```
>
> as a variant of `error` that will get its call-site. We can access the call-stack inside `errorWithCallStack` with `callStack`.
>
> ```
> errorWithCallStack :: HasCallStack => String -> a
> errorWithCallStack msg = error (msg ++ "n" ++ prettyCallStack callStack)
> ```
>
> Thus, if we call `errorWithCallStack` we will get a formatted call-stack alongside our error message.
>
> ```
> >>> errorWithCallStack "die"
> *** Exception: die
> CallStack (from HasCallStack):
>   errorWithCallStack, called at <interactive>:2:1 in interactive:Ghci1
> ```

(I'm guessing `msg ++ "\n"` was meant, but `"n"` is what is written.)

While you can get some very limited stack trace support with GHC 7.8 and on, I would recommend upgrading to GHC 8 if possible for significantly better support. Either way, it won't be what you are used to from other languages, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: In the latest GHC release, `error` *is* `errorWithCallStack`. And the docs seem to suggest you get better stack traces from a profiled build than using `HasCallStack`. I haven't tried the profiled way yet.

Comment: @dfeuer Do I understand the claim correctly that GHC 8.2.1 w/ `-prof` should produce better call stacks?  It doesn't seem to be so: https://gist.github.com/TomMD/7d1fb8dc762fc37bf80b7b7dd447e29a

Comment: Even with profiling enabled (via `stack build --profile`), I see only the error message "divide by zero" with no additional context.  Let's say there is a codebase in which the division operation (`/` or `\`div\``) appears at dozens of call sites.  When one encounters the error message "divide by zero" at runtime, and any of those call sites seem to be equally likely candidates as the source of error, how does one approach debugging?  Must one swap out each instance of the division operation with some annotated version (at best, narrowing down the offending call sites in a binary search)?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, I really don't know, but take a look at https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#compared-with-other-sources-of-stack-traces

Comment: I don't see any such implication there.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson `-prof` with `-fprof-auto` or manually added SCC annotations make more descriptive callstacks.

Comment: Indeed.  While it doesn't retain/print the entire stack it does yield the final function that actually calls error. Useful.